# Define local variables in another function

Tags: php, object, functional-programming

I've been looking at [Magic Constants](http://php.net/manual/en/language.constants.predefined.php) and [Reflection](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reflection.examples.php) in PHP to see if the following is possible:

```
function one() {

  setVars();

  // $node would be in scope
  print_r($node);

}

function setVars() {
  return $node = '2';
}
```

Is this a classical programming concept? Reflection seems to be the closest thing. Basically, I just want to define variables in a different scope (the scope/context of the function that called the setVars() function).

Comment: `$node` wouldnt be in scope there. you would have to do `$node = setVars()`... unless im missing something.

Comment: Maybe I should be more clear. I would intend to set MULTIPLE variables in setVars(). Return wouldn't work here

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/functions.returning-values.php#example-158

Comment: you could return an array and then use `extract`... or jsut use the variables in the array.

Comment: @prodigitalson or just use the `list` syntax like in the example I posted, which was made for this purpose.

Comment: @mavame I don't understand why one would do that.  If you want to tightly couple two different functions like that, why not put them in a common class so that all the methods would have access to the class properties (which could be set with a method like `setVars`)?

Comment: I really like @prodigitalson's approach using `extract`. I created this pen to demonstrate: http://codepad.org/oqlEP2gG

Comment: @MikeBrant Typically, I'd be all for the Class approach, but in this case, we are using within the context of a CMS (Drupal) in the theme layer, and I shy away from introducing new OO structures at that point. Thanks for the idea, though.

Answer (score 1):

For more than one variable try to store them in a array and return the array.

```
function one() {

  $nodeArray = setVars();
  print_r($nodeArray );

}

function setVars() {
  $nodeArray[] = 1;
  $nodeArray[] = 1;
  $nodeArray[] = 1;
  return $nodeArray;
}
```

Comment: I should have been more clear. I want to define MULTIPLE variables, not just one.

Comment: This is MULTIPLE dear. The difference is i stored the values in a array.

Comment: Except that your example returns only one value. I would then need to run `extract` on the result to have multiple local variables defined inside one(). Thanks for your answer

Comment: This one array can be splited easy by [list()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.list.php).

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at extract().

```
function one() {

  $vars = setVars();
  extract($vars);

  // $node1 would be in scope
  print_r($node1);

}

function setVars() {
  $node1 = '1';
  $node2 = '2';
  return compact('node1','node2');
}
```

It should be said, although this is possible, it often leads to terrible architecture and problems down the line.

Comment: There is no need to compact and extract I think.

Comment: No, probably not, but the question was asking about defining local variables in another scope, and I think this is the closest you get to that.